# android and ios app subscription checking in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm creating app that is only available on subscription, no free or trial version. In react native, how do I check if the user has a valid active subscription? Is there any api I need to call?

On the app load or login time, I want to check if the user still has valid subscription and if not just not let the user to login into app.

Another question I have is do I even need to do this? Does android or ios automatically uninstall or restrict access to app if the subscription is expired?

Answer (score -1):

To sell subscriptions or products in a React Native App use the [react-native-iap](https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap) library.

After implementing it rightly and buying a subscription you can use the getAvailablePurchases function to get list of the bough products by the users.